# Run head script on server side nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-meta, nuxtjs2

I'm trying to add meta script tag to nuxt page inside head tag

```
 head() {
return {
  title: 'Test',
  script: [
    {
      vmid: 'meta1',
      innerHTML: `console.log('test')
    `,
      type: 'text/javascript',
      body: true,
    },
  }
 }
```

If ssr:true script not working successfully. How can do with on ssr:true on Nuxt js project

Comment: please use stackbliz to generate minimal reproducible example

Comment: Did you try to define the head meta data at nuxt page's `async function`?